# How can I combine the results of 2 queries into 1 output?

Tags: sql

Summary of the project: I am trying to make a report on my local chevy dealership to gather their numbers online and when their sales numbers are low, I will strike and lowball them to get a good deal.

Here's what I am currently trying to do:
I have to use two separate queries that I am using to create cars sold report and cars gain report.

EX:

| Model | # of vehicles sold |
| --- | --- |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 Custom | 3 |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 LT | 22 |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 LT (2FL) | 5 |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 LTZ | 5 |

Table 2:

| Model | # of vehicles added |
| --- | --- |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 Custom | 4 |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 LT | 2 |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 LT (2FL) | 3 |
| Chevrolet Silverado 1500 LTZ | 7 |

Is there any way I can combine the two so instead of having 2 seperate tables I can just have 1?

I dont think union is what im looking for,
I cant get the
Select
(query 1)
(query 2)
to work

I dont know if what I am trying to do is achievable in SQL but I figured its worth a try.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Why not `JOIN` the two tables on the `Model` field, then calculate the delta between the two quantity fields to get your result?

Comment: Please tag an RDBMS and provide some sample DDL, illustrate what you’ve tried so far by including a [mre], being sure to explain succinctly why your attempt doesn’t meet your requirements. See [ask]

Comment: You need full outer join if car models can be missing on either side of the join yet should still be in the result.

Comment: Why did you create two similar tables?

Comment: Do a `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.MODEL,t1.[# of vehicles sold],t2.[# of vehicles added]
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
on t1.MODEL = t2.MODEL
```

Assuming you are using t-sql and MODEL values are unique. Those column names are not good.